# Getting helper method to run on initial update of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My goal is to get the autoPagination function to run when this.props.userSaves initially updates in state. In my program it starts out as an empty array, and on initialization 100 objects are stored in the array. The problem is that autoPagination is running before the objects get stored, and thus the while loop isn't running. I've fixed this using setTimeout but I don't really see that as a long-term solution. Any ideas?

The below code is nested in a class based component.

```
  autoPagination = async token => {
    while (this.props.userSaves.length > 0) {
      const { userSaves } = this.props
      const lastPage = userSaves[userSaves.length-1].data.name

      const userSavesObject = await axios.get (`https://oauth.reddit.com/user/${this.props.username}/saved/.json?limit=100&after=${lastPage}`, {
      headers: { 'Authorization': `bearer ${token}` }
    })
      const currentPageSaves = userSavesObject.data.data.children
      this.props.storeUserHistory(currentPageSaves)
      this.props.appendUserHistory(currentPageSaves)
    }
  }
```

Full component (since requested):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { storeUserHistory, appendUserHistory, storeInitialData } from '../actions/index.js'

class ListSaved extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount (props) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.hash);
    const token = params.get('#access_token')
    this.props.storeInitialData(token)

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.autoPagination(token);
    }, 3000)
  }

  autoPagination = async token => {
    while (this.props.userSaves.length > 0) {
      const { userSaves } = this.props
      const lastPage = userSaves[userSaves.length-1].data.name

      const userSavesObject = await axios.get (`https://oauth.reddit.com/user/${this.props.username}/saved/.json?limit=100&after=${lastPage}`, {
      headers: { 'Authorization': `bearer ${token}` }
    })
      const currentPageSaves = userSavesObject.data.data.children
      this.props.storeUserHistory(currentPageSaves)
      this.props.appendUserHistory(currentPageSaves)
    }
  }

  renderPostTitles = () => {
    return this.props.totalSaves.map((saved) => {
      return (
        <div key={saved.data.id}>
          <div>{saved.data.title}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }

  render () {
    return <div>{this.renderPostTitles()}</div>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state)
  return { 
    username: state.username,
    userSaves: state.userHistory,
    totalSaves: state.totalUserHistory
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { storeUserHistory, appendUserHistory, storeInitialData })(ListSaved);
```

Comment: This method only gets called when the component is created. try calling it in `shouldComponentUpdate()` and if possible post the component

Comment: Calling it in shouldComponentUpdate creates an infinite loop. And gives me the error ListSaved.shouldComponentUpdate(): Returned undefined instead of a boolean value. Make sure to return true or false on. -- on each loop

Comment: It shouldn't create an infinite lnfinite loop but cannot no more without seeing the component. Always return a bool in the `shouldComponentUpdate()` function so just add `return true`

Comment: Tried that, still runs in an infinite loop. Didn't post rest of the component since I didn't think it was relevant to the Q, and would probably just confuse people. Only other things in the component are a componentDidMount that stores the access token, and a mapping function to display titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a variable and set it true initially.. Run the function when you get data in your props and make the variable false so that it don't run again..

```
constructor (props)
{
   super(props)
   this.myvar = true
}

componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps)
{
    if(this.myvar)
    {
         if(check if get your data)
           {
               // run your function 
              this.myvar= false
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: ComponentWillReceiveProps is marked as UNSAFE and deprecated since React 16.3

Comment: Ok. We can use the same approach in componentDidUpdate then.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Component. Every-time the component updates the function is run. Component is updated a first time right after mounting

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { storeUserHistory, appendUserHistory, storeInitialData } from '../actions/index.js'

class ListSaved extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount (props) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.hash);
    const token = params.get('#access_token')
    this.props.storeInitialData(token)
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate (props) {
    this.autoPagination(token);
  }

  autoPagination = async token => {
    while (this.props.userSaves.length > 0) {
      const { userSaves } = this.props
      const lastPage = userSaves[userSaves.length-1].data.name

      const userSavesObject = await axios.get (`https://oauth.reddit.com/user/${this.props.username}/saved/.json?limit=100&after=${lastPage}`, {
      headers: { 'Authorization': `bearer ${token}` }
    })
      const currentPageSaves = userSavesObject.data.data.children
      this.props.storeUserHistory(currentPageSaves)
      this.props.appendUserHistory(currentPageSaves)
    }
  }

  renderPostTitles = () => {
    return this.props.totalSaves.map((saved) => {
      return (
        <div key={saved.data.id}>
          <div>{saved.data.title}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }

  render () {
    return <div>{this.renderPostTitles()}</div>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state)
  return { 
    username: state.username,
    userSaves: state.userHistory,
    totalSaves: state.totalUserHistory
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { storeUserHistory, appendUserHistory, storeInitialData })(ListSaved);
```

Comment: I have tried this way before, and I have also tried subscribing to the redux store so it updates everytime the store does. Neither work. Anytime the autoPagination function is run in such a way it enters into an infinite loop that crashes chrome. Just FYI I copy/pasted the code to test and it went into an infinite loop again. That's why in the OP I'm interested in only getting it to run once.

Comment: ```
const currentPageSaves = userSavesObject.data.data.children
      this.props.storeUserHistory(currentPageSaves)
      this.props.appendUserHistory(currentPageSaves)
```
this is the part that causes the infinite loop. Make sure that you do not change the props, props should be accessed in a read-only manner